# NSURL not working

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I wanted to ask if anyone could help he get this code to work. Nothing is showing up in my MySQL database. Thanks, enbr.

```
NSString *urlstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://mysite.come/myapp/submitrating.php?name=%@&comment=%@&rating=%@",
                    [selectedItem objectForKey:@"name"], comment.text, selectedRating];
NSString *urlstrEncoded = [urlstr stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlstrEncoded];
[urlstr release];
[url release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with this code.

```
NSString *urlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysite.com/myapp/submitrating.php?name=%@&comment=%@&rating=%@", [selectedItem objectForKey:@"name"], comment.text, selectedRating];
NSString *urlEncoded = [urlstr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlEncoded];
NSString *ans = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do much more than that!  At minimum you need the following:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];



NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

along with implementing the following methods:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

Comment: I tried this method but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're not *doing* anything with the URL object except creating it. Perhaps you want to try an `NSURLConnection`?